# Mazda 323P,Electrical circuit of engine control

Tags: electrical, mazda, throttle-position-sensor

For me is necessary the electric diagram of engine control Z5 and the procedure regulation of throttle position sensor.

Comment: What year is your car? What engine does it have? And to understand, you are looking for the procedure for setting the throttle position sensor?

Comment: Are you looking for an electrical diagram for your car?

Comment: I restore the automobile Mazda 323P of 1998.The electrical circuit of engine control is necessar. Engine mazda Z5-DOHC.

Comment: In this engine it is necessary to very accurately adjust throttle position sensor. Otherwise heavy expense of fuel…

Comment: I'm not sure which engine the Z5 is, but this is the procedure for the [1997 Mazda Protege engines](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12618/fast-idle-and-high-fuel-consumption/12620#12620). The Protege's are called 323's elsewhere in the world for those years. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Paulster2! Sensor disposed, now I attempt to explain, why revolutions at the idling sail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which engine the Z5 is, but [this is the procedure](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12618/fast-idle-and-high-fuel-consumption/12620#12620) for the 1997 Mazda Protege engines. The Protege's are called 323's elsewhere in the world for those years.